# response of react native get request gets status text undefined

Tags: http, react-native, http-error

I'm new to React Native and I'm calling an API with params. It looks like this.

```
   async onSendClick() {

    AsyncStorage.getItem('@Token:key').then((token) => {
    console.log("console is " + token)

    let subject = "Feedback Form"
    let senderEmail = 'test@test.com'
    let fromEmail = 'us@test.com'
    let replyTo = 'customer@test.com'
    let url = BASE_URL +  '/email/send?'
    let params = "subject=" + subject + "&email=" +senderEmail +  "&fromEmail=" + fromEmail + "&replyTo=" + replyTo + "&content=" + feedBackMessage


    return fetch(url + params , {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
          },
        }).then((responseOne) => {
            console.log(responseOne)
        if (responseOne.status == 200) {
            console.log("success")
        } else{
          console.log("error")
        }
        }).catch((error) => console.error("ERROR" + error)); 
      })
  }
```

In the response section , I'm getting 404 error with statusText: undefined. Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must encode the URI. Otherwise it will not work.
Follow [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) for more info about URL encoding in javascript.